# How to delete Cell Factories references

Tags: java, javafx, callback, tablecellrenderer

I have a JavaFx application which allows to open detached windows. The detached windows are loaded from fxml files. Within the fxml there is a table with columns. When a window is closed (stage closing in is equivalent to stage hiding) my window controller object is still alive because of some callback references associated with table cells.
The callback is associated with the cell like this:

```java
@FXML
private TableColumn<MyModel, Boolean> colImage;
// ...   

colImage.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<MyModel, Boolean>, TableCell<MyModel, Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<MyModel, Boolean> call(
            final TableColumn<MyModel, Boolean> btnCol) {
        final TableCell<MyModel, Boolean> cell = new TableCell<MyModel,Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(final Boolean ack,
                    final boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(ack, empty);
                if (ack != null) {
                    if (ack) {
                        final ImageView colIconNew = buildIconImageView(
                                ICON_CHECKED, generalImageLookup);
                        setGraphic(colIconNew);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        };
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Is there any way to delete these references after window closing action? I tried to set a null callback after closing action occured like this:

```
colImage.cellFactoryProperty().set(null);
```

but it didn't work.
Any Idea?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you think the reference to the controller is getting retained? Once the table has no live references, then its columns presumably will have no live references. What is the actual symptom of the problem?

Comment: I monitored the application instances with jvisualm and the controller is still alive after stage closing. Commenting the above lines of code (so that the default renderer is used) makes it ok and the controller instance disappear. But I need a custom rendrer as described.

Comment: Not sure if this fixes it (actually I'm not sure there's really an issue at all), but you should do this anyway: you're creating a new `ImageView` every single time the `updateItem(...)` method is called. You should create one for the cell, and reconfigure it (if necessary) in the `updateItem` method. I.e. move `final ImageView colIconNew = ...` outside of the `updateItem()` method.

Comment: By doing like you suggest I'll create it even when I don't need it! And the table is filled only once without any other update. Anyway, try to trust me, the issue is in the callbacks which retain the cell references even if the table is not visible anymore. By commenting these lines all becomes fine.

Comment: `updateItem(...)` is called many times when you just scroll in the table. So you are likely creating hundreds of `ImageView`s and discarding them immediately. You can lazy initialize if you need, but only create (at most) one image view per cell. Seems a bit misplaced to be worrying about garbage collecting the cell when you are throwing away vast chunks of memory usage like this.

Comment: oook. you're right. I'll fix this. Any idea about how to garbage collecting the cell? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: my cells get garbage collected appropriately. Probably you need to [edit] your question to include a [MCVE]. There's no way the compiler can optimize that away, btw.

Comment: Ok. I will do. Thanks